# In Headlessui/Combobox, is there a way to reach clicked option when multiple options selected?

Tags: reactjs, combobox, headless-ui

I have a Headlessui/Combobox. Selected items are displayed in bold font and with a tick icon in dropdown. And i am displaying these items in another component. ***What I want is when I click on an item that I have already selected, I want this item to be unselected. I want to perform some kind of toggle operation.*** I thought about finding the item I was clicking at that moment and removing it from the entire array. But onChange event displays all selected items. Here =>

```
<Combobox>
  onChange={item => {
    console.log(item)); // Shows all the selectedItems
  }}
</Combobox>
```

How can I access the item I clicked at that moment?

Combobox Component:

```
    return (
        <Combobox
            as="div"
            onChange={item => {
                handleClick(item[item.length - 1]);
            }}
            disabled={!isEditable}
            className="disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-30"
            value={selectedResults}
            multiple
        >
            <Combobox.Label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                {t('Search')}
            </Combobox.Label>

            <div className="relative mt-1">
                <Combobox.Button disabled={true} as="div" className="flex items-center">
                    <Combobox.Input
                        className="disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-30 w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        displayValue={person => person?.name}
                    />

                    <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center rounded-r-md px-2 focus:outline-none">
                        <ChevronUpDownIcon
                            className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                    </span>
                </Combobox.Button>

                {searchResults.length > 0 && (
                    <Combobox.Options className="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
                        {searchResults.map(person => (
                            <Combobox.Option
                                key={person.nanoid}
                                value={person}
                                className={({ active }) =>
                                    classNames(
                                        'relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9',
                                        active ? 'bg-indigo-600 text-white' : 'text-gray-900',
                                    )
                                }
                            >
                                {({ active, selected }) => (
                                    <>
                                        <span
                                            className={classNames(
                                                'block truncate',
                                                selected && 'font-semibold',
                                            )}
                                        >
                                            {person.name}
                                        </span>

                                        {selected && (
                                            <span
                                                className={classNames(
                                                    'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4',
                                                    active ? 'text-white' : 'text-indigo-600',
                                                )}
                                            >
                                                <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                                            </span>
                                        )}
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </Combobox.Option>
                        ))}
                    </Combobox.Options>
                )}
            </div>
        </Combobox>
    );
}
```